# How can I make flexible layout where a div is sized to fit in the viewport, and scroll if necessary

Tags: css, layout, scrollbar

I'm trying to make a layout that flows depending on the orientation of the viewport (portrait, landscape), so I'm styling my divs as inline-block, which works nicely.  However, I want my second div to only take up available space (regardless of orientation) and have a scrollbar if need be.  I have a non-working fiddle here:  http://jsfiddle.net/47mdp/ (it reflows if you change the size of the result window, but the second div goes past the bottom edge of the window if the result window is small)

```
html, body{
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
div#wrapper{
    top: 0px;
    height: 100%;
}
div#first, div#second{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 150px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    vertical-align: top;
}
div#second{
    overflow: auto;
}

<div id="wrapper">
<div id="first">
    <p> first div </p>
    <p>some more stuff in first div</p>
</div>
<div id="second">
    <p>stuff</p>
    <p>stuff</p>
    <p>stuff</p>
    <p>stuff</p>
    <p>stuff</p>
    <p>stuff</p>
    <p>stuff</p>
    <p>stuff</p>
</div>
</div>
```

The solution would ideally be css only.

EDIT:  this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/47mdp/1/ makes my second div go to the bottom of the window, as I want, but does not move under the first div when the window is narrow (which I also want - and the first fiddle does this).  Basically, setting position:absolute seems to be a no-go because it defeats my inline-block display.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking, but try giving your second div a defined height or max-height... like 100%. That should force a scrollbar on overflow.

Comment: Yes, I understand that if I give the second div a defined height it will work, but I want the second div to go to the bottom of the window.  I tried setting postion: absolute and bottom: 0px, but that makes it not act like an inline-block.

Comment: @Aerik do you want like this? [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/47mdp/2/).

Comment: @Mr_Green that looks like half of it - your second div resizes the way I want, but when the window is narrow I want it to reflow under the first div (then only be a height that fits in the window).  I'm trying to make a page with two boxes, where the second box's size is a) dynamic and b) positioned either next to or under the first box depending on orientation...

Comment: @Aerik like this? [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/47mdp/3/).

Comment: No, the second div is not supposed to cover up the first.  But using your basic idea, I did this http://jsfiddle.net/47mdp/5/ which does what I want as long as the first div's height is known.  Not too bad a solution, but feels clunky...

Answer (score -1):

You need to define the height of the second div